# OLE and/or runtime 438 errors when pulling Word Form data into Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

This script worked perfectly... until it didn't. I have an Excel workbook in the same folder as multiple copies of a Word form. The macro should pull the data from each form and copy it to a row in the workbook. I now get either "OLE Excel is waiting on another application" errors or Runtime 438 errors. The macro I use is as follows:

```
    Sub GetFormData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim CCtrl As Word.ContentControl
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
    i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docm", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
        i = i + 1
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile,   AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
      j = 0
    For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
        j = j + 1
        WkSht.Cells(i, j).FormulaLocal = CCtrl.Range.Text
        Next
    End With
    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

   Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

The issue appears to start at "Set wdDoc = wdApp..."

I am a bit of a noob at this. As such, I appreciate your help.
    Matt.

Comment: Do `wdApp.Visible = True` before anything else, and see if there is a message.

Comment: @GSerg Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. It still returns the 438 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible issues, the first one is almost certainly causing the error; the second *could* cause this error (but probably not with VBA):

1. You declare and instantiate the Word application in the same line:

   Dim wdApp As New Word.Application

You shouldn't do this. Instead:

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
```

I don't remember the exact details about the "why", but it's something to do with the Word.Application object being created immediately, and at a level where you can no longer control it using `Set wdApp = Nothing`.

2. Correctly, all objects of the "outside" application should be released, in reverse order of their creation. You've declared an object of the type `Word.ContentControl`, but don't release it:

   Set Set CCtrl = Nothing : Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing

Comment: Cindy -Thank you so much! That fixed all the issues. I appreciate your time.